# Rank of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Say a $5\times 5$ matrix 
$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3&4&5\\
6&7&8&9&10\\
11&12&13&14&15\\
16&17&18&19&20\\
21&22&23&24&25\\ \end{array} \right] $$

or $n\times n$ in general, is there a quick way of **finding the rank** of this kind of matrix without using any row operations?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this particularly special matrix, you can observe that if you look at a particular row $r$, then it is the average of row $r - i$ and row $r + i$ (provided $r - i \geq 1$ and $r + i \leq 5$, so that the rows we're talking about are actually there).  More generally, though not necessary, is that row $a$ + row $d$ = row $b$ + row $c$ for $1 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq d \leq 5$ such that $a + d = b + c$.

This tells you that all the intermediate rows are linear combinations of the first and last row, which are visibly linearly independent since neither is a multiple of the other.  Hence, $\text{rank}(A) = 2$.

Comment: Very nice observation, thank you very much!